# Generic Methods with Linked-list

Tags: java, generics, methods, linked-list

Hi I'm trying to make these 2 methods work, but even though I tried pretty much everything I can think of, it's still not working. Please tell me how to fix it!

**void add(Anything value):** Adds a node containing newValue to the end of the list.
**void addAfter(int index, Anything value):** Adds a Node node containing newValue after the node of index index(assume index start in 0).

Here's my code: (*The methods above appear at the bottom*)

```
public class Node<Anything>
{

private Anything data;
private Node next;

Node(Anything a, Node<Anything> n)
{
    data = a;
    next = n;
}

public Anything getData()
{ 
    return this.data;
}

public Anything setData(Anything newData)
{
    Anything oldData = this.data;
    this.data = newData;
    return oldData;
}

public void setNext(Node<Anything> newNext)
{
    this.next = newNext;
}

public Node<Anything> getNext()
{
    return this.next;
}
 }


------------------------------------------

 
public class CS2LinkedList<Anything>
{  

private Node<Anything> first;
private Node<Anything> last;

public CS2LinkedList()
{
    first = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (first == null);
}

public void addFirst(Anything d)
{
     Node<Anything> temp = first;
     first = new Node<>(d,temp);
}


public void clear()
{
    first = null;
}

public boolean contains(Anything value)
{
    for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.getNext())
    {
        if (value.equals(curr.getData())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();  //String result = "";
    for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.getNext())
        result.append(curr.getData() + "->");  //result = result + curr.data + "->";
    result.append("[null]");
    return result.toString();   //return result + "[null]";
}


public int size()
{   
    int size = 0;
    for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.getNext()){
         size++;
         if (first==null){
                 size = 0;
            }
        }
        return size;
         }
    

public Anything getFirst()
{   
   
    if (first!=null){
        return first.getData();
    }
    else{
       System.out.println("Sorry, the list is empty.");
       return null;
    }
    
}

public Anything getLast()
{
    if (first!= null){
        
        for(Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.getNext()){
            first = curr;
        }
        return first.getData();
        //FIX: list2's size decreases by 1 after executing list2.getLast()
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Sorry, the list is empty.");
        return null;
    }
}

public void add(Anything value){
    if (first==null){
        first = new Node<>(value,first);
    }
    
    Node<Anything> next = new Node<>(value, first);
    first.setNext(null);
    last = next;
 }

public void addAfter(int index, Anything value)
{
    return;
}
 }
```

Comment: " it's still not working. Please tell me how to fix it!" in what respect doesn't it work?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: With the first method (add(Anything value)), I want it to organize the elements in the list in such fashion that when I print it, it prints backwards. But when I print the list, it still prints in the opposite direction.

ex) list3.add("node1"); list3.add("node2"); list3.add("node3");
     System.out.println("3-element list: " + list3);
This prints node3, node2, node1, and I'm trying to print it in reverse.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I don't understand how this is not already backwards.  How is "3,2,1" not already in reverse?

Comment: Are you aware that you are setting the next node of first to null? I think it isnt adding the next node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A bit long answer, tried to explain every bit of problem and give the solution. Have patience!**

You're code is exactly doing what you have told it to do, adding new nodes **in reverse**. It is adding the `new node` as the `first` and set the `current first` as new node's `next` while `addFirst()` is called.

But with the current `add()` method you've mentioned, you'll always get a linked list not more than `one` element by calling the `printing toString()` method, although you have the list containing **not more than** two nodes. Let's look at your code to understand this:

```
public void add(Anything value){
    if (first==null){
        first = new Node<>(value,first);
    }
    
    Node<Anything> next = new Node<>(value, first);
    first.setNext(null);
    last = next;
}
```

So what you are doing is, you're checking whether the `first` is null, which means, whether the current list is empty. If `true` then initialize `first` with new value (say `"x"`) and it's next as `current first`, which is `null`. So we get `[first(x)] -> [null]` as our current list.

Next you're initializing a `next` node with the `value` and `first` as it's next. Then you are setting the next of `first` as `null` and assigning `next` to the `last`. So far we've got:

```
[next(x)] -> [first(x)] -> [null]        //where last node is next(x)
```

Now if you want to `add(y)`, another `next` will be initialized with the current `first` as the next of this new node. Then again redundant making of `null` of the `next` of the `first`. And again assigning this new node to `last`. Now we've got:

```
[next(y) -> [first(x)] -> [null]
```

So, here we go! You are losing the `current last` by assigning the new node to the `last`, and this `last` will have the `first` as it's next, always, how many nodes you want to add, it follows the same path.

Hence, you'll get a linked list of `two` elements, always, with this `add()` method.

**But why the toString() gives only `[first(x)] -> [null]` as linked list?**

Well, look at the `toString()` function, it starts from `first`, runs until `first.next == null`. And, you have `first.next == null`, always, if you add nodes with this `add()` method. Therefore, such behavior of the `toString()`.

**What's the solution?**

Set both of the `first` and `last` of the linked list in the constructor as null during the initialization. In the `add()` method, initialize the `first` for the first time with the `value` and `last`. And assign it to the `last`. `return` after that as we are done adding the first node. Remove the `first.setNext(null)` statement, initialize the `new node` with value and `null`. Make the `next` of the `current last` as `new node`. and assign the new node as the last. Here is the code:

```
public void add(Anything value) {
    if (first == null) {
        first = new Node<>(value, last);
        last = first;
        return;
    }

    Node<Anything> next = new Node<>(value, null);
    last.setNext(next);
    last = next;
}
```

Now if you print the `toString()`, you'll get:

```
node1->node2->node3->[null]
```

Hope you got your answer and desired solution!